# Does a TransactionScope that exists only to select data require a call to Complete()

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions

In order to select data from part of an application that isn't affected by dirty data, I create a TransactionScope that specifies a ReadUncommitted IsolationLevel as per the suggestion from Hanselman [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx).

My question is, do I still need to execute the oTS.Complete() call at the end of the using block even if this transaction scope was not built for the purpose of bridging object dependencies across 2 databases during an Insert, Update, or Delete?

Ex:

```
List<string> oStrings = null;
using (SomeDataContext oCtxt = new SomeDataContext (sConnStr))
using (TransactionScope oTS = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
{
     oStrings = oCtxt.EStrings.ToList();
     oTS.Complete();
}
```

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx, "When a TransactionScope object joins an existing ambient transaction, disposing of the scope object may not end the transaction, unless the scope aborts the transaction. If the ambient transaction was created by a root scope, only when the root scope is disposed of, does Commit get called on the transaction. If the transaction was created manually, the transaction ends when it is either aborted, or committed by its creator."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it hasn't changed any data, then it won't *itself* do anything - but yes: it **should** have a `Complete()`, because there might be an *outer* transaction-scope around this one. If yours rolls-back, you've doomed the whole *outer* transaction. By completing your transaction you allow the outer transaction to continue unhindered.

Note that `Complete()` in this scenario is "free" anyway; in fact SQL Server *always* optimises towards `Complete()`, with rollback (`Dispose()` without `Complete()`) being the expensive one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A transaction can only end in a completion or a rollback, so if you don't complete it, it will automatically rollback. That would be more expensive even if there is no actual changes to undo, and it might possibly affect other transactions.